# My Repo on BitBucket is not synced with my local project

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket

I go to bitbucket, i see the other coder performed a commit.
I performed a git pull from his code before updating my local code

however now I am trying to push the code and I am unable to

Here is my command line

```
git status
nothing to commit, working directory clean
git add .
git commit -m "Adding all files"
nothing to commit, working directory clean
git push -f
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you have committed your changes, you have pulled the latest from remote, you seem not to have any merge conflicts, and you have tried to do `git push -f`. Last thing to understand is in what way you are unable to push. what is the output of `git push -f`?

Answer (score 1):

You are not pushing your code, you just commited locally, you must do `git push origin <branchName>`

Comment: I forgot to copy and paste the last line. It's not being pushed

Answer (score 0):

First of all it looks like you dont have any files to commit.
Once you have some content you have to push it.

Since you dont have any content you dont have anything to push as well.

Looks like your files are in ignored by git.

To display a list of all your ignored file:

```
git check-ignore *
git check-ignore -v *
```

Comment: I forgot to mention the last line in my question.

Comment: looks like you dont have any files to commit

Comment: I know I do because I changed some of my source code files. Xcode attempted to update the repo then there was an error message and now I can't update from command line

Comment: but maybe those files are ignored by GIT? if you dont have any files in status so there is nothing to commit.

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: `git check-ignore *`  `git check-ignore -v *`

Comment: Updating my answer accordingly your comment

Comment: I did that and nothing spit out in my terminal

Comment: are you in the root folder? if you are it means that are no updated file. edit any file or create a new one and see if it displayed in `git status`

Comment: Yes I'm in the root folder, typing ls -lha shows me the .git file.

Comment: have yo utry adding any new file and run git status? echo 'a' > a.txt; git status

Comment: git status shows the newly created file but git push origin develop
says Everything up-to-date. nothing is pushed to the repo

Comment: you need to do this: git add . && git commit -m "my message" && git push

Comment: What if I copy my code, delete my local folder then download the "latest" on the git repo and then paste my modified files back?